# merging datatables in R based on conditions

Tags: r, datatable

Firstly,I have tried to find solution via documentation of datatable library of R but didnt help.I have two data datatables which has key gender and weight.How do i merge them with condition `t1$gender == t2$gender` and `t1$weight <= t2$weight`?

Here is tables:

```r
t1 <- data.table(ID = c(1:6), gender = c("m", "m", "m", "m", "f", "f"), w = c(1:3))

t2 <- data.table(gender = c("m", "f", NA), w = c(1, 2, 3), z = c(4, 2, 3))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use a non-equi join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(t1)[t2, .SD, on = .(gender, weight <= weight)]
```

---

If we are also interested in the 'z' column

```
setDT(t1)[t2, c(.SD, .(z = z)), on = .(gender, w <= w), nomatch = FALSE]
#   ID gender w z
#1:  1      m 1 4
#2:  4      m 1 4
#3:  5      f 2 2
```

Comment: It helps but it doesnt return any other columns other than those two,Im newbie in R sry for that.

Comment: @ttosun Not clear without a reproducible example and what you expect.  If you want to some column in 't2', then use the `i.` or if it is unique column, just specify the name of that column name

Comment: I have an extra columns ID and z but it doesnt print out in terminal.

Comment: @ttosun What do you get with this code `setDT(t1)[t2, .(ID, z), on = .(gender, weight <= weight)]`

Comment: oh thx for your answer,lastly z column only appers to be in second datatable and when we use merge function it doesnt create a problem but here it throws an error since z doesnt exist in one table.Why using merge function doesnt throw an error because of z?

Comment: @ttosun Sorry, without a small reproducible example, it  would be a waste of both of our times to do this conversation

Comment: Added example tables to my question.

Comment: @ttosun Please check if the updated solutioin is your expected